# What order are files added to the DataTransfer FileList when dragging and dropping files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, fileapi

I'm building a web application where users drag images into the browser and drop them to upload them. The problem is, I would like the files to upload in the same order as the folder they dragged them from. It seems like the files in the ondrop event's DragEvent.DataTransfer.FileList are sequenced randomly. How is this order determined? Is it possible for me to determine the original order of the files in the folder the user dragged them from?

Answer (score 5):

After testing it a bit more I found the answer. The files are in the same order as the folder, but are offset to start with the actual individual file that you dragged in. So, if you highlight 5 files and drag them in by clicking on the third file and dragging, the order will be file 3, file 4, file 5, file 1, file 2. As for my second question, it would seem that finding the proper order would be contingent upon knowing the offset of the file dragged in. I haven't found a way to determine this yet.

Comment: I was trying to determine what behaviour was occurring and after seeing your comment I have understood and verified that this is the case, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Created [a codepen](https://codepen.io/cagerattler/pen/OZqdBy) to look into this further, using promises, as recommended, to handle nested directory structures:

```
  function getFilesDataTransferItems(dataTransferItems) {
   function traverseFileTreePromise(item, path = "", folder) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (item.isFile) {
            item.file(file => {
                file.filepath = path || "" + file.name; //save full path
                folder.push(file);
                resolve(file);
            });
        } else if (item.isDirectory) {
            let dirReader = item.createReader();
            dirReader.readEntries(entries => {
                let entriesPromises = [];
                subfolder = [];
                folder.push({name: item.name, subfolder: subfolder});
                for (let entr of entries)
                    entriesPromises.push(
                        traverseFileTreePromise(entr, path || "" + item.name + "/", subfolder)
                    );
                resolve(Promise.all(entriesPromises));
            });
        }
    });
  }

  let files = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let entriesPromises = [];
    for (let it of dataTransferItems)
        entriesPromises.push(
            traverseFileTreePromise(it.webkitGetAsEntry(), null, files)
        );
    Promise.all(entriesPromises).then(entries => {
        resolve(files);
    });
  });
}
```

As Andrew points out, when a group of selected files is imported via drag and drop and dataTransfer, the files are reordered with the file that is dragged first and then wrapping to the actual first file.  Confirmed this in Chrome and Firefox.

It gets even more complicated with nested directories.  The order of files in a subdirectory is lost and the files are placed in alphabetical order with same level subdirectories last.

I'm afraid these are current limitations of the dataTransfer object as an experimental technology.